# Will the List<> clear its value if this method is recalled?

Tags: c#, winforms, list

I have a method that is composed of `List<>` which will change based on selected fields.

If i recall the method which is composed of different values are the items on the List removed?

I declared the method like this:

```
private int mymethod(int g)
{
    List<int> list1 = new List<int>();
    List<int> list2 = new List<int>();
    List<int> list3 = new List<int>();
    return list1.Sum();
}
```

Answer (score 3):

In your case though list1 doesn't have anything assigned to it, so i wonder what are you tring to sum here. And to answer your question specifically *Yes list1 will be re-created on each method call*.

You need to understand the [scope](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa691132%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) of variables here. Any instance that is created within the method will not be accessible outside it's bounday.

Comment: Well you can use closures to hold on to them!  =)

Answer (score 2):

Yes, the value of the local variables inside a method will be cleared once the method terminates. The values are not preserved each time you call.

you could declare the list outside of the method .

Answer (score 0):

If you re-initialize the instance you composed, yeah.
It will replace the new instance with the last one.

Answer (score 0):

The actual `List` objects themselves will not just be cleared, but won't even exist after the method returns.  They will be recreated each time the method is called.